# Transitioning from Contract to Full-time, pay issue

Tags: salary, new-hires, transition

Recently I moved from being contracted to full-time at my company. In transition, however, some internal paperwork got messed up and I was listed as having two start dates. 12/12 and 12/19. The problem here is I was under the impression that from 12/12-12/18 I was still under contract, and submitted a time sheet to the contractors, and now it comes out that I may not have been under contract.

What happens if I receive payment from both companies for the week in question? I was told I may be asked to return the amount I received, but is that before or after taxes? I don't think it fair that I be asked to pay the pre-tax amount, for an issue that isn't my fault.

Looking for a bit of insight as to what I might be in for.

Comment: You really think you will be asked to return one and still be both 1099 and W2.

Answer (score 4):

If you were overpaid, the correct thing to do is tell your payroll department.

To find out if you were overpaid, verify what your official start date is and confirm this with everyone involved.

Also, don't spend the money you believe was accidentally paid. This happens often enough that while it seems obvious, it's worth saying.

> I was told I may be asked to return the amount I received, but is that before or after taxes?

It would be the amount you received, so after taxes.